# Method that returns reverse of an array.

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

Trying to write a java method that returns the numbers of array reversed. But I get an error message:"This method must return a result of type int[]."

```
public int[] reverseValues (int[] values) {
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length / 2; i++) {
        int temp = values[i];
        values[i] = values[values.length - 1 - i];
        values[values.length - 1 - i] = temp;
    }
```

Any suggestions what i have done wrong.

Comment: you forgot return statement

Comment: Looks like you have some unbalanced `{}`, also, you specify you are going to return an `int[]`, and you don't have any return statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot `return values;` operator in the end of method ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem by returning an int[] (as Andremoniy said) or by declaring the method `void`.

Answer (score 1):

@Andremoniy says you are missing the

```
return values;
```

Statement.

But in your case you seem to try to modify the original array (values) at that moment your method should be void and not int[].

However it is usually bad practice.
You should preferably return int[] but at that moment you should work on a local array, fill it with the reverse values and finaly return it.